# reload UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a certain code that is executed on the viewDidLoad() of a UIViewController I have. The problem is that it is only loaded for the first time only. After it is loaded the first time and I switch to some other view and come back to this view, it doesn't call the viewDidLoad again. So where should I put this code at so that everytime this view is displayed it executes this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess in `viewWillAppear`
good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` . This gets called every time your view comes on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to life cycle of iphone application

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

should only be called once.

so you should use,since this method is called each & every time the View is called

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```